# New nested resource with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have this route:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :services
  resources :contacts
  resources :title_abstracts
  resources :parcels
  resources :leases
  resources :documents
end
```

this is in my Projects View to add a new Contact to the Project:

```
new_project_contact_path(@project)
```

The url produced is:  http://localhost:3000/projects/15/contacts/new

And the Contacts Controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @contact = @project.contacts.build
end

def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @contact = @project.contacts.build(params[:contact])
  @contact.save

  redirect_to project_path
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
 Couldn't find Project with 'id'=
```

What am I doing wrong?
How should I test this?

Comment: You should probably sanitize `params[:contact]`. And what is the line causing the error? Is it (`@contact = @project.contacts.build(params[:contact])`)?

Comment: Are you sure `@project` in your link (`new_project_contact_path(@project)`) is not nil?

Comment: It is:  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

Comment: can you post new `contact`'s view ?

Comment: take a look at the params sent to your controller and eventually post them here.

Comment: <%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %> - I bet I need to pass in the project

Comment: Request parameters 
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J1Ytc8DrDkTVknPTcsetxvNcGdRa/HPx9qjZe6X4hQV7uWoJNrE0GV1RGsMsiJ+wPjIdj1zQxoLKzf2TCcV50Q==", "contact"=>{"first_name"=>"New", "last_name"=>"", "phone"=>"", "bus_phone"=>"", "email"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact", "controller"=>"contacts", "action"=>"create"}

Comment: instead of `simple_form_for @contact do |f|` try with `simple_form_for [@project, @contact] do |f|`. This will add a project_id field to your form and will fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes.rb you nested `:contacts` in `:projects`.
 but when you use `simple_form_for`, you cannot implicitly declare `<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>`. You should pass the `url:{controller: :contacts, action: :create, project_id:@project.id}` as an argument along with the new `@contact` instance to `simple_form_for`. so that `params[:project_id]` will be available in your controller.

If you really wish to use `<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>`, you need to add
`resources :contacts`     to your `routes.rb` file but you need to optimize your controller action code for desired routing. I think it would help you.Thank you.